# How to determine the File Extention in the Bilsen Ribbon Project

Tags: delphi, ribbon-control

I use Delphi but I would be happy to get an "C" answer as well.
http://bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, so whatever information is at the site you've linked to should be summarized in your question.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, you do this all with The TActionlist
here is a property TFileSaveAs or TFileOpen.
Sorrz I did not see this